# Get image width and height and write them to local files

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of HTML files with images that do not have width and height attributes set.

In the HTML file I have something like: `<img src="image1.png" alt="image one"></img>`

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically get image height and width and write to the local HTML files the image width and height using the image name in the source document as the condition for inserting the two attributes.

Basically what I need is to get the `<img />` tag and insert the actual width and height values of the referenced image. All the images are saved in the same local directory as the source HTML files.
 So my final  should look like: `<img src="image1.png" height="100px" width="230px" alt="image one"></img>`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First of all, `img`-tags are self-closing, they do not need an ending `</img>`-tag. Secondly, why would you need this? Those attributes are [not required](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Training/Image#Image_size).

Comment: I need this to include this information before doing an XML conversion of the HTML files.

Comment: Can you display these images on the page you're doing this on? If so, it's pretty easy through jQuery. If you can't display them, I'm not sure how it would know the correct size.

Comment: What ManUO needs is a simple shell script, not something to do this when displaying the page in a browser. They need the actual file rewritten with width and height attributes.

Comment: Yes, Nate has a good point, if you want to do this to the actual html file we'll first need to know your OS.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy B. I am using Mac 10.9, Windows 7.

Comment: @ManUO: what you need is some sort of shell script, written in bash or node or something similar. It's not terribly complicated, but it probably involves learning how to do a bunch of new things. If you're familiar with JS, it might be easiest to use Node. This will give you a start: http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/nodejs-shell-scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have the picture is loaded correctly you can use try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var imgHeight = $('img').height();
    var imgWidth = $('img').width();

    $('img').attr('height',imgHeight+'px').attr('width',imgWidth+'px');

});
```

[check full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henkvonh/7tdjY/)

When the picture is loaded, you check the length and width with jquery. Then you add them as attributes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the question, if I understand it correctly. To quote myself from above: "What ManUO needs is a simple shell script, not something to do this when displaying the page in a browser. They need the actual file rewritten with width and height attributes."

Comment: If that's what he needs then his tags are probably incorrect.

Comment: Hm, kind of presumed he meant that he wanted the attributes in the DOM because of the tag javascript :/

Comment: Thanks @Nate for understanding and clarifying my question. The reply from Henry does not address the issue I need to solve.

Comment: @Jeremy/Henrik You're both right, but I'm surprised that was a powerful enough red herring to make you misinterpret the question itself. I've edited ManUO's question to remove the JavaScript tag.